# Alternative to android's official SDK, to create an android Keyboard

Tags: linux, android, software-development, ubuntu

Now that eclispe's SDK is depreciated, I'm stuck with android studio, which I absolutely hate. Moreover, java and I are not best friends :)

How to create a soft keyboard using anything other than Android's official sdk?

Any Lua or Python or similar solution? C++ is fine as far as i know it can't be done using NDK.

Or if i must go for java, any easier sdk than the official sdk? Please no android studio

Other requirements:

- Free, not necessarily open source
- Ability to make the keyboard a system wide keyboard
- I can use rest api or other web services, say i want to connect to a server and display something to the user
- Doesn't lag on mobile and isn't heavy and work on old devices, I tried kivy, I don't know if their keyboard can be used as a system wide keyboard, but a friend told me that it lags too much and isn't recommended.
- Optional: Runs on Linux, ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, or smoothly in wine. But if that's not an option, I have virtualbox running windows.
- Optional: Doesn't take too long to compile into APK, kivy takes ages.
- Optional: Well documented, well tested, many examples
- Optional: The app can be easily ported to IOS
- Optional: isn't too hard to install like MOAI sdk, and MOAI can't do what I want anyway.

I looked at, Cocos2d, Corona, Moai, Godot, Love2d, NDK, they can't do what I'm asking for. Kivy can, but I'm not sure that the keyboard can be made as a system wide keyboard and I've been told that it lags, so it's not an option right now, unless you use kivy and know for sure that kivy doesn't lag and can be used to make a system wide keyboard.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you hate Android Studio ? I personally was relieved to be able to ditch Eclipse .... IMO, it would be useful to the people who would try to answer your question if you included something about what you hate so they can avoid recommending something with similar characteristics :)

Comment: @2Dee I'm old school, learn to develop android apps on eclipse, studio is so different, have to learn everything from scratch, and I hate gradle

Comment: You can have eclipse shortcuts on AS, maybe that could be a start? I recommend you give AS another chance, I found that once I got used to it, my productivity increased significantly, partly thanks to using gradle. There are articles around on the web addressing the issue of changing your Android IDE, I'll see if I can find that back when I get home if you're interested (I'm on mobile right now).

Comment: @2Dee sure I'll be so thankful for your help :)